# A GMail Script to unstar email loop

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-apps

I have emails in my inbox and ones that get archived throughout the day.  Every night I want to create a script to automatically unstar them for the next day.  I created this script but it doesn't seem to work.  The Google docs don't seem to be much help in the way of syntax.

Here is the code I was using.  Will this code access the archive as well?

```
function processInbox() {
  var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var firstThread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0];
    var message = firstThread.getMessages()[0];
    GmailApp.unstarMessage(message);
 }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are working only on the first thread in your inbox.

```
GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0];
```

You needed to put your 'i' variable in that line in order to iterate on the messages.

Try something like that:

```
// first limit the script for the top 50 emails (or a bit more) but don't run on ALL of them -it's not efficient.
var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0, 50);
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var message = threads[i].getMessages()[0];
    GmailApp.unstarMessage(message); 
}
```

Good luck.